# How to group rows using LINQ to Entity separating values with commas?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities, string-concatenation

Below is my LINQ Query, that im using to select `ITEMS`:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    whatsmydiscountEntities ctx = new whatsmydiscountEntities();

    int IdRelationshipItems = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["IdRelationshipItems"]);
    int IdProductService = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["IdProductService"]);

    var Items = (from es in ctx.State
                join ie in ctx.ItemsStates on es.StateId equals ie.StateId 
                join i in ctx.Items on ie.IdItem equals i.IdItem 
                join iir in ctx.ItemsRelationshipItems on i.IdItem equals iir.IdItem
                join ir in ctx.RelationshipItems on iir.IdRelationshipItems equals ir.IdRelationshipItems 
                join ips in ctx.ItemsProductsServices on i.IdItem equals ips.IdItem 
                join ps in ctx.ProductsServices on ips.IdProductService equals ps.IdProductService
                 where iir.IdRelationshipItems == IdRelationshipItems
                && ips.IdProductService == IdProductService
                && ir.Active == 1 
                && i.Active == 1
                select new
                           {
                               ItemName = i.Name,
                               StateSigla = es.Sigla, 
                               ProductServiceName = ps.Ttitle, 
                               RelationshipItemName = ir.Name, 
                               RelationshipItemImage = ir.Image, 
                               RelationshipItemActive = ir.Active, 
                               ItemSite = i.Site,
                               ItemDescription = i.Description,
                               ItemAddress = i.Address,
                               Iteminformationdiscount = i.information_discount,
                               ItemLogo = i.Logo,
                               ItemActive = i.Active,
                               StateId = ie.StateId, 
                               IdRelationshipItems = iir.IdRelationshipItems,
                               IdProductService = ips.IdProductService
                            }).ToList();
}
```

As you can see, the result will be 1 row for each state, if the user passes the `IdRelationshipItems` and the `IdProductService`.

Instead of 1 row for each state with the same information, I'd like to show only 1 row and all the states separated by commas. What do I need to change to do this?

Comment: Example desired output and how it look now would help.

Answer (score 0):

I had to solve this problem today. I have a view model that looks like this:

```
public class IndexViewModel
{
    public string Search { get; set; }
    public IPagedList<MembershipUser> Users { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> Roles { get; set; }
    public bool IsRolesEnabled { get; set; }
    public IDictionary<string,string> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

I needed to return a unique list of users and all of the Tags that are assigned to them as a comma separated string.

The data is stored like this:

"41FFEC0F-B920-4839-B0B5-862F8EDE25BD", tag1
"41FFEC0F-B920-4839-B0B5-862F8EDE25BD", tag2
"41FFEC0F-B920-4839-B0B5-862F8EDE25BD", tag3

And I needed output that looked something like this:

"41FFEC0F-B920-4839-B0B5-862F8EDE25BD", "tag1, tag2, tag3"

I ended up creating a List of UserId's like this (I'm using the MembershipProvider which exposes the UserId as ProviderUserKey):

```
var userIdList = users.Select(usr => (Guid) usr.ProviderUserKey).ToList();
```

The object "users" is a MembershipUser object. I then call a function in my service passing the List in like this:

```
Tags = _usersTagsService.FindAllTagsByUser(userIdList)
```

And my service function looks like this:

```
public IDictionary<string, string> FindAllTagsByUser(IList<Guid> users)
    {

        var query = (from ut in _db.UsersTags
                    join tagList in _db.Tags on ut.TagId equals tagList.Id
                    where users.Contains(ut.UserId)
                    select new {ut.UserId, tagList.Label}).ToList();

        var result = (from q in query
                     group q by q.UserId
                     into g
                     select new {g.Key, Tags = string.Join(", ", g.Select(tg => tg.Label))});

        return result.ToDictionary(x=>x.Key.ToString(),y=>y.Tags);
    }
```

I'm pretty sure these two linq statements can probably be combined into one but I find it easier to read this way. Still only hits the database once.

**Things to watch out for**:

1. I was originally passing just IList users into the function FindAllTagsByUser and linq couldn't infer the type and therefore wouldn't let me use the .Contains extension method. Kept saying that linq to entities didn't support Contains.
2. You need to do a .ToList() on the first query to materialize it or you will get trouble from linq to entity when you try to use string.Join to create the comma separated list.

Good luck

dnash

Comment: Thanks a lot. ill give i try. if i dont come back, it´s because i made it. =)